# Highcharts - with datetime axis labels overlap

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts and I have a chart with a datetime axis.
Most times the labels are correctly distributed along the axis with no overlap.

But sometimes it happens that labels overlap.
Here you can see an example: http://jsfiddle.net/4ghhf/
Using tickInterval and tickPixelInterval doesn't solve the problem.

What should I do to avoid the problem?

Answer (score 10):

I see two ways of fixing your problem :

- Change the tick interval
- Change the label display

I applied both in the following code (xAxis section) :

```
$(function () {
 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column'
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval : 7*24 * 3600 * 1000,
        labels : { y : 20, rotation: -45, align: 'right' }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2010, 3, 11), 29.9],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 4, 8), 71.5]
         ]
    }]
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't use those solutions.

Comment: Chart data is loaded dynamically;setting tickInterval would cause labels overlap in charts with long time periods.Also setting tickInterval dynamically,depending on the time interval,is not a solution,since the chart is zoomable and zooming cause labels overlap.
I also can't rotate labels, since I have to copy the design of our designer(the jsfiddle I linked was just a simple example to let understand the problem).
I tried to use tickPixelInterval but when the time period is short, like the example, pixels are not respected and labels overlap.
Why does this happen? Is there really no solution?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe staggerLines is a solution for you:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        staggerLines: 2
    }
},
```

I updated your jsfiddle with this setting: http://jsfiddle.net/benebun/4ghhf/134/

From the [API Ref](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.staggerLines):

> **staggerLines:** Number (Since 2.1)
>
> Horizontal axes only. The number of lines to spread the labels over to make room or tighter labels. .

(found via [this comment](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/193#issuecomment-714585) on github)

I updated your jsfiddle with this setting: http://jsfiddle.net/benebun/4ghhf/134/

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use tickPixelInterval, which defines the pixel spacing between the ticks. A higher number will result in fewer ticks.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPixelInterval

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer here: [Highcharts overlapping category labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732154/highcharts-overlapping-category-labels)
I was using a category array for xAxis labels instead of letting HighCharts parse a UTC date code.

Answer (score 0):

It can also depend on the Font you are using. With me this happens for Arial, but works fine with Helvetica or Times New Roman.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and fixed with the [**autoRotation** configuration](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.autoRotation). Highcharts will automatically rotate your labels if they don't fit. If there are too many even when rotated Highcharts will try remove labels automatically for you.

```
xAxis = {
    "type": 'datetime',
    "tickInterval": 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    "labels": {
        autoRotation: [45]
    }
}
```

Just make sure you don't specify **step** as it will override autoRotation.