# Highcharts overlapping category labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need help with a problem with category labels for xAxis. When there is no room for all the category labels, they get crammed together and overlap each other.

I have searched to see if I could find some way to ensure that this does not happen, first I looked for a scrolling solution, then some sort of zooming, and eventually I tried to go for staggerLines.

The problem is, if I am to use staggerLines, I need to set the value depending on the number of categories I have. If I have 10 or less, staggerLine value is set to 1, 11-20 I want it stet to 2, 21-30 I want to set it to 3 and so on. I can not simply just set it to 3, because some times it will be just a few categories shown, and that won't look good with staggerLines.

Anyone have a good suggestion for how to solve this?

Comment: Not posting this as a solution since this definitely needs to be fixed in HighCharts but what we do is for all category xAxis data charts we have the xAxis vertical. That way text is horizontal for the labels. Dirty fix but it works for our data once we have the chart dimensions set correctly.

Comment: Funny, I have the opposite problem (using 4.0.4). Categories are truncated because they don't fit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to use categories at all. In general categories are good to show e.g. fruits, or names - how to define which name should be displayed, and which shouldn't? Is apple more important than banana?

However, solution is pretty simple, using xAxis label formatter, take a look: http://jsbin.com/oyudan/27/edit

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function(){
      return names[this.value];
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: The secret here is to make sure you don't use "categories: Names," in the xAxis definition. The the chart is smart enough to grab the labels it needs.